# breakpoints are not being hit while remote debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, weblogic

I am running a remote debug session in eclipse, connecting to weblogic (10)
In the 'Server Start' the parameters are specified:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8115,server=y,suspend=n
```

...and in the Eclipse debug configuration, I have the port and server name specified.

This was working fine for more than a year for me.  Today, with no changes on my part, an application I am trying to debug, is NOT hitting breakpoints.  Basically it looks like debugger is NOT active, while everything seems as it is.  Where can I look to diagnose and to mediate the problem?

Thanks

Comment: When you say that there are no changes to the app do you mean that you haven't rebuilt the app or that you have rebuilt the app but there were no code changes going into the build?  I ask because there are requirements on the compiler options in order to be able to debug remotely.

Comment: Chris, the application has been changed back and forth. Changes were by me and not only by me. I meant there was changes to server configurations that I mentioned above. I was using the debugger end of last week, and it was OK. Is there anything I can check on the server ? What are those compiler options? I did upgrade my eclipse environment. But, didn't redeploy the ear file since I changed eclipse environment. I tried with the eclipse I had previously, and got the same issues.  Eclipse doesn't connect to jvm on the server

Comment: On the Java Compiler properties page (for java projects in Eclipse) are some class file options that should are all be checked